# Can/should I index an embedded document in Mongoose?

Tags: mongodb, node.js, mongoose

I have the following schemas; Address is a geocoded location and Agency has many addresses. My question is, if I want to be able to perform a geospatial search on agency based on its addresses then do I need to somehow index them at the agency level (already indexed at the address schema level)?

Also, I'm having a hard time finding information regarding how to find based on nested documents. In this scenario, is it even possible to do what I am hoping for or should I expand out my domain structure a bit and have an "AgencyAddress"? This approach seems a bit RDBMS to me but I can also see the advantages of it.

I'm a bit confused about how I could use ObjectId refs from Agency (or a bridge object AgencyAddress) without an inverted link back from address. I don't want to have back links because address will be used by a number of other objects in the app.

Thanks!

```
var AddressSchema = new Schema({
  name        : {type: String, default : ''},
  street1     : {type: String, default : ''},
  street2     : {type: String, default : ''},
  city        : {type: String, default : '', required: true},
  state       : {type: String, required : true},
  zip         : {type: String, default ''},
  country     : {type: String},
  location    : {longitude: Number, latitude:Number}
  type        : {type: String, enum:['agent', 'agency', 'registrant'], index:true}
  created_at  : {type: Date, default: Date.now},
  updated_at  : {type: Date, default: Date.now}
  primary     : {type: Boolean, default: false}
});

AddressSchema.index({location: '2d'});
```

**Agency:**

```
var AgencySchema = new Schema({
  name         : {type : String, default : '', required : true},
  Type         : {type : String, enum['medical', 'disaster-service', 'local-law', 'state-law', 'federal-law'], index:true},
  Addresses    : [Address], 
  created_at   : {type : Date, default : Date.now},
  updated_at   : {type : Date, default : Date.now}
});
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I dont have experience with the mongoose, so i can explain mongodb indexing in general. From your question i understand that multiple `Address` geocoded docs embedded into Agency.

If you are using mongodb version <=1.8, its not possible to index the nested geocoded documents. But the feature is added from version 1.9 . I have been successfully using for couple of months for the same kind of schema. But it was a development(unstable) branch.

luckily version 2.0 is released a week ago. And its stable. Check out the link [2.0 Release Notes](http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/2.0+Release+Notes#2.0ReleaseNotes-GeospatialFeatures) for more info.

And you cannot index directly on embedded documents.

it has to be done like this from mongodb shell

```
   db.Agency.ensureIndex({"Address.location": 2d})
```

I don't know the exact syntax for mongoose, may be like this

```
  AgencySchema.index({'Address.location': '2d'});
```

check out the [mongodb indexing](http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Indexes#Indexes-IndexingonEmbeddedKeys%28%22DotNotation%22%29) for more info

Comment: It doesn't feel perfect to me. Is it really a requirement that the index gets created in the mongo console?!

Comment: @Greg "Is it really a requirement that the index gets created in the mongo console", not at all, you can do that via any language driver you use, i said it from console because i dont have any experience with mongoose

Comment: @ramesh got it. i was generalizing your answer in part because the dot notation was failing for me. but i realized i was missing the quotes. thanks.